# RxJs operators are not recognized while running angular tests

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, rxjs, observable

So, I have a component where I subscribe to change in value in one of the form control on ngOnInit life cycle.  But while writing tests the tests for it, I get an error relating to skip not being a function.

My Component file looks like this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
    this.cronTextSubscription = this.cronForm.get('emailCron').valueChanges
      .skip(3)
      .debounceTime(3000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(cronPattern => {
        this.updateEmailCronPattern(cronPattern);
      });
    this.fetchCronExpression();
  }
```

While running the test, I get the following error.

```
 TypeError: this.cronForm.get(...).valueChanges.skip is not a function
```

I am new to testing in angular, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax is from RxJS 5. Check if in test you are using RX5 or 6. If you are using 6 then you should use .pipe instead

Comment: Using the pipe instead worked for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If this code works in the project but has issues in tests then you need to verify that in the test `this.cronForm.get('emailCron')` returns correct data.

Also you use here quite old rxjs syntax, please check your rxjs version. perhaps it's 6 (but in this case the project should fail too).

Then your code should look like:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
    this.cronTextSubscription = this.cronForm.get('emailCron').valueChanges.pipe(
      skip(3),
      debounceTime(3000),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(cronPattern => {
      this.updateEmailCronPattern(cronPattern);
    });
    this.fetchCronExpression();
  }
```